# Make parent onPressed be on top of its child's onPressed

Tags: flutter

I am drawing a bar graph using the charts_flutter package. In this package, you can tap on the chart's bars. However, i have a FlatButton as its parent widget. I would like to press anywhere on the bar graph and have the onPressed() function of the parent FlatButton run.

Sample code:

```
FlatButton(
    child: BarGraph(this.data),
    onPressed: () {
        _changeGraphType();
    },
 )
```

Is there a way to remove "press-ability" from a child?

Comment: i want to call _changeGraphType() when the bar graph is pressed. I want to remove the 'onPressed()' that comes from BarGraph(this.data)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the bar chart under GestureDetector (or InkWell) widget. It'll detect the user tap. Sample code :

```
    GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          _changeGraphType();
        },
        child: BarGraph(this.data),
      )
```

Comment: With GestureDetector, the margins of the graph (which previously worked as intended because I wouldn't tap/press directly on the graph) no longer change the graph. This solution doesn't work, sorry :/